# django: double file upload: js and html

Tags: django, http-headers

I have 2 django models:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload/', blank=True)

class  Preview(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='preview', blank=True)
```

Then I create `ImageForm` with `ModelForm` and render it in the html template.
I want to do image preview in the page.
I use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#id_photo').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '{% url preview %}',
            always: function (e, data) {
                $('#preview').css({'visibility': 'visible'});
                $('#preview').prepend('<img src=/static/'+data.result.url+' />')
            }
        });
    });
</script>

    <form method="POST" action="edit/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field">
        {{ form.photo.errors }}
        <label for="id_photo">Photo:</label>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="id_photo" >
    </div>

    <div id="preview">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="Change">
```

So with the help of `javascipt` I send image to server, resize it (in `preview` view  -  it process `PreviewForm`), save on disk and return the url which is inserted into `img` tag. It works.

After I press *Submit* button I can't receive image file in my view (`edit` which process `ImageForm`) : request.FILES is empty !!!
When I disable "uploading image with js"  'edit-view works fine: `request.FILES` contain image, and i can save it..

what causes disappearance `request.FILES` in second `POST` request ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to learn is `HTTP` is `stateless` protocol. Every request a client does to a server is unique and independent from the previous one.

In your situation, you *submit* your form with the image that you want to upload and it makes the upload so that you can see the image in `request.FILES` and display a preview for it.

However, once you make the upload and show a new page, of course `request.POST` will be empty because you did not uploaded anything, the file is already in your server, waiting to be approved.

The proper solution will be, when preparing the preview, create some `hidden` input fields which will help you to identify what photo you want to approve (`unique ids` are very good in this case, also don't expose file paths directly to your client unless you are the only one who's using the app).

Then in the second request, retrieve those `hidden field`s, locate the image and do what you are going to do; in your case, approve and make it public somehow.

Comment: > However, once you make the upload and show a new page, of course request.POST will be empty - I don't show new page. Page don't reload, and other post variable (name ..) is present in request.POST!

Comment: It does not matter whether you make the upload via javascript or regular way. It is the protocol. The reason the other fields are there because they are still in the page, they are sent to server _again_ while the file is not uploaded again.

Comment: Yes and he used ajax, there is nothing to do with page reloading